# Python Regedit Как создать папку в реестре

Tags: python, regedit, winreg

Мне нужно создать папку в реестре. Возможно это сможет сделать winreg, но в документации я ничего не нашёл. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы можете использовать библиотеку `winreg` в Python для создания папки в реестре.

```
import winreg

# Определите путь к разделу реестра, в котором вы хотите создать папку
path = r"Software\MyApp\Settings"

# Откройте раздел реестра для записи
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path, 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE)

# Создайте новую папку с именем "NewFolder"
new_folder_name = "NewFolder"
winreg.CreateKey(key, new_folder_name)

# Закройте раздел реестра
winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

Этот код создаст новую папку `"NewFolder"` в разделе `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\Settings`. Вы можете изменить переменную `path`, чтобы указать путь к другому разделу реестра, и изменить переменную `new_folder_name`, чтобы задать другое имя папки.

Обратите внимание, что для создания папки вам может потребоваться соответствующее разрешение доступа на запись в реестр.